# Помогите решить задачу по c++ пж

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

**Условие:**

Даны два числа N и K. Требуется изменить число N так, чтобы в его двоичном представлении K младших разрядов остались неизменными, а все остальные были заменены на 0.

В задаче запрещено использовать арифметические операции +, -, *, / и %, а также операторы if / switch и тернарную операцию.

**Формат входных данных**

В одной строке вводятся два целых числа N и K (1 ⩽ K ⩽ 30, 0 ⩽ N < 231). Разряды нумеруются от младшего к старшему начиная с нуля.

**Формат выходных данных**

Требуется вывести одно целое число — ответ на задачу.

**Пример:**

**входные данные:** 1023 5

**выходные данные:** 31

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, x;
    cin >> a >> b;
    c = 1 << b;
    c = c | ~c;
    d = a & c;
    cout << d;
    return 0;
}
```

Он почему=то вообще не меняет число, помогите, пожалуйста.

Надо использовать побитовые операции (<< и >>) и &, ^, |, ~.

Comment: `c = c | ~c;` - какой тут был замысел? `c | ~c` ставит все биты в 1, нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну да, я и хотел поставить все биты в 1, чтобы исключить все биты, кроме первых 5-ти.

Comment: Но на предыдущей строке вы пишете `c = 1 << b`, а потом на `c = c | ~c` выбрасываете полученное значение и заменяете его единичками.

Comment: Так в этом и смысл. Допустим, есть число 10110011001, и я хочу последние 5 его символов, я просто сделаю конъюнкцию с числом 11111 и получится 11001, по идее.

Comment: После `c = c | ~c` там будет не `b` единичек, а сколько влезет (фиксированное число, скорее всего 32). По идее эту строчку нужно заменить на `c--`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N &= ~(0xFFFFFFFF << K);
```

Так даже лучше :) -

```
N &= ~(~0 << K);
```

Comment: Как... солидно... ;D

Comment: а что такое 0xFFFFFFFF?

Comment: @TAWER768 4294967295, 2^32